# Bootstrap panel fit to page height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the panel and image to be at a fixed height so that it is not larger than the page and there is no scrollbar. How would I archive this?

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Panel</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/16864258_1261558947267706_6364934376555931917_n.jpg?oh=99e2734014dbdc9080048e0c6022e132&oe=5973503B" width="100%" height="100%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/58br0n1g/

Comment: If the image is fixed height, it can't be relative to the page which varies in hieght? Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can tackle this problem.

Firstly you want to constrain the height of the panel, using `max-height: 100vh;` this sets the max height of the panel to 100 viewport height units, which 100% of the height.

Secondly we need to handle the image, Since you've set the image to 100% 100%, the image might overflow the container. Thus you need to decide how the image will be display. You have several options here:

1. Add `overflow: hidden;` to the panel, meaning any excess image will just not be shown.
2. Use `background-image: url(/path/to/image.jpg);` in CSS instead of an inline image element. This means you can take advantage of the various background-size properties, for example `background-size: cover;` will make sure the image always fills 100% of the background. Worth doing some research around this.

Hope that helps.